# How to list DISTINCT ALL products from database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Currently when a user would open this web page, all of the products in the database are listed on the page. Some products show up in multiple categories which means that they are listed multiple times, how can I limit them to showing up once?

Comment: You could do something, like get 12 random ids and use them in the query, eg ```SELECT * FROM product WHERE productId in [ your random id list] and product_status = '1'";```

Comment: I'm not clear why selecting a category would show no results as you claim, when the user makes a new choice you have to clear all products and the request the new selection, i don't know what you are trying with the category but make an ajax request to your php and generate a new product list

Comment: When a user selects a category, you would just do a different query no? Maybe the picture you painted in your question is not 100% clear. Do you want 12 random items to appear or not? Are they actually random, or related to another parent product?

Comment: You will have two sql queries. One on page load, and one when a user selects a category. Use the one like in the answer my Szymek on load, and create a new one for when a user selects a category. Really simple stuff.

Comment: Another thing, your tag states Javascript and this is PHP.

Comment: You would do so by following the suggestion above by @nbk when there is an event that involves a user selecting a category ```make an ajax request to your php and generate a new product list```. I am not going to code this for you. Your site can have more than one SQL query on it. So write another SQL query that returns the results you want, like ```select * from products where categoryid = 'whatever category is selected'``` and on page load, use a query like the one in @Szymek gave you below.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see some examples on how you can choose random records from database. However, keep that in mind, that described method is not the most efficient one.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx

In your example, it would just need to be:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_status = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12";
```

Comment: That is because you need another query