# How to SELECT DISTINCT *

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this a possible query?

Currently, every product from my database is being listed on the home page of my website and a lot of them are duplicates since a product can belong to multiple categories.

I am using `"SELECT * FROM Books WHERE product_status = '1'";`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Strangers on the internet have no idea what *you* mean by "duplicates".  Why would a table called `product` have duplicate products anyway?  Something seems wrong with the data model.

Comment: And which category do you want to select ? Is it the same to you ?

Comment: There are currently 65 categories so I would need them all to show

Comment: But for your example you say: "A book can fall under 2 categories such as "Nonfiction" and "Biography"" so for that book do you want to show "Nonfiction" or "Biography" under the column `Category`? You have to know the logic for this kind of columns and only then you can create a query...

Comment: Either one it doesnt matter, I just want to make sure it only shows up once on the page.

Comment: If you are doing `SELECT * FROM Books` and getting duplicates, then take a closer look at your database design. There is an error there somewhere in the way you link your categories. There should be no reason for 2 `Book` rows just because a book is in 2 categories

Comment: The categories to which each book belongs should be stored in a separate table.

Comment: You posted the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868435/how-to-list-distinct-all-products-from-database. If you really want an answer then post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use group by and max.

```
select column1, column2, max(category)
from Books 
WHERE product_status = '1'
group by column1, column2;
```

In this example column1 and column2 are your columns from table Boooks (like book_title, book_author or something similar...) and you can select max(category) so only one category is selected....

Here is the small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b8674b9cba32687655ea4e5a309c7b8)

In this demo only one of two same books is selected. 
Book with ID 4 is not selected because it has product_status = '0'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202590/discussion-on-answer-by-vboksic-how-to-select-distinct).

Comment: Thank you @SamuelLiew I was looking how to do it. Never done it before... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a (semi-)normalised design. I would hope that the further steps towards normalisation (to 3NF) would be reasonably self-evident:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;

CREATE TABLE books(book_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO books (title) VALUES ('small green squares'),
('large green squares'),
('small green triangles'),
('small yellow triangles'),
('large red circles');

SELECT * FROM books;
+---------+------------------------+
| book_id | title                  |
+---------+------------------------+
|       1 | small green squares    |
|       2 | large green squares    |
|       3 | small green triangles  |
|       4 | small yellow triangles |
|       5 | large red circles      |
+---------+------------------------+

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books_categories;

CREATE TABLE books_categories
(book_id INT NOT NULL
,category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(book_id,category)
);

INSERT INTO books_categories VALUES 
(1,'small things'),(1,'green things'),(1,'square things'),
(2,'large things'),(2,'green things'),(2,'square things'),
(3,'small things'),(3,'green things'),(3,'triangular things'),
(4,'small things'),(4,'yellow things'),(4,'triangular things'),
(5,'large things'),(5,'red things'),(5,'circular things');

SELECT * FROM books_categories;
+---------+-------------------+
| book_id | category          |
+---------+-------------------+
|       1 | green things      |
|       1 | small things      |
|       1 | square things     |
|       2 | green things      |
|       2 | large things      |
|       2 | square things     |
|       3 | green things      |
|       3 | small things      |
|       3 | triangular things |
|       4 | small things      |
|       4 | triangular things |
|       4 | yellow things     |
|       5 | circular things   |
|       5 | large things      |
|       5 | red things        |
+---------+-------------------+
```